# A geometric ordering problem

Tags: geometry, analysis, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis

The following problem occurred to me the other day.

Given two distinct real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ (let's call them points in $\mathbb{R}$). Trivially, I can always find a third point that it's either closer to $x_1$ than to $x_2$ or vice-versa. In other words, I can always solve either
$$
|p-x_1|<|p-x_2|\,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\,|p-x_2|<|p-x_1|
$$
for some $p\in\mathbb{R}$.

Extending this thought to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and considering three non-collinear points $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$, can I always solve
$$
|p-x_i|<|p-x_j|<|p-x_k|
$$
for any permutation of $i,j,k$, where $i,j,k\in\{1,2,3 \}$ and $i\neq j\neq k$. That is, ordering $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ in any of the $6$ possible ways, can I always find a point which is closest to the first point, second closest to the second and so on?

It might slightly boring to prove, but I believe the answer to be yes, where non-collinearity is trivially needed. For example,

[image]

I wonder, however, how to argue when extending this problem to $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, given $n+1$ points not lying in the same hyperplane, can I always find a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
|p-x_{i_1}|<|p-x_{i_2}|<\cdots <|p-x_{i_{n+1}}|
$$
for any permutation of indexes $\{i_k\}_{1\leq k\leq n+1}$? If the answer is positive, and if there are infinitely many solutions, what kind of set is the solution set?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Essentially, you're creating a Voronoi diagram: starting with a fixed set of points $P=\{p_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ not all contained in a hyperplane, except the boundary every point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is in one Voronoi cell (that is, it satisfies one permutation of $<$ among the indices).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjRq8.png

Wikipedia gives a nice description of how to construct these cells.

Comment: I like the idea of using a Voronoi diagram (I work with these a lot). So, the idea is to basically look at the $n$-dimensional version of the Voronoi tessellation generated by $n+1$ seeds? But how do I relate its definition with the permutations I'm imposing? And what would be $p$ in this case, a new seed?

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the $\Bbb R^2$ case first: Consider the lines $L_{12}, L_{13}, L_{23}$ perpendicular to and passing through the midpoints of the line segments $\overline {x_1x_2}, \overline{x_1x_3}, \overline{x_2x_3}$ respectively. Each of these lines divides the plane in two. All points on the $x_1$ side of $L_{12}$ are closer to $x_1$ than $x_2$, and all points on the $x_2$ are closer to $x_2$ than $x_1$.

If the three lines intersected in a triangle, then for a point $p$ inside the triangle for an appropriate relabeling $x_1, x_2, x_3$, you would find that $px_1 < px_2, px_2 < px_3, px_3 < px_1$ would hold, requiring that the distance from $p$ to $x_1$ be strictly less than itself. Hence, it must be that $L_{12}, L_{13}, L_{23}$ intersect in a single point $C$. This is the well-known result that given any three non-colinear points, one can always find a circle that passes through them.

The three lines therefore break the plane into six wedge-shaped regions having $C$ as their apex. In each of these regions the distances of points to $x_1, x_2, x_3$ is ordered per one of the six arrangements of those points, thus showing that indeed, all arrangments are possible.

For higher dimensions, instead of the $L_{ij}$ being lines, they are hyper-planes of codimension $1$. But given $n+1$ points in general position in $n$-dimensional space, there is always a point that is equidistant from all of them, so once again, all the $L_{ij}$ must intersect in that point, dividing $\Bbb R^n$ into conic regions where the distances to each of the $x_i$ are ordered per one of the orderings on the $x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

If the $n+1$ points are not lying on a hyperplane, we can solve the linear system of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\phantom{0} & x_1^T & \phantom{0} & 1 \\
\phantom{0} & x_2^T & \phantom{0} & 1 \\
\phantom{0} & \vdots & \phantom{0} & \vdots \\
\phantom{0} & x_{n+1}^T & \phantom{0} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\phantom{0} \\
p \\
\phantom{0} \\
c
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 (x_1^Tx_1 - a_1) \\
\frac12 (x_2^Tx_2 - a_2) \\
\vdots \\
\frac12 (x_{n+1}^Tx_{n+1} - a_{n+1})
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The condition "The points are not lying on a hyperplane" means that the matrix on the left side is invertible.

Once we solved this equation, we have
$$
x_i^Tp + c = \frac12 (x_i^Tx_i - a_i)
$$
or
$$
p^Tp - 2x_i^Tp + x_i^Tx_i = a_i + p^Tp + 2c
$$
or
$$
(p-x_i)^T(p-x_i) = a_i + p^Tp + 2c
$$
which means that I can adjust the differences of the squares of the distances $\|p-x_i\|$ however I like, by means of the $a_i$.

Example:

If I want $\|p-x_2\| < \|p-x_3\| < \|p-x_1\|$, I can simply set $a_2 = 0,$ $a_3 = 1$ and $a_1 = 2,$ calculate $p$ as shown above and I will get
$$
\|p-x_2\| = \sqrt{r + 0} \\
\|p-x_3\| = \sqrt{r + 1} \\
\|p-x_1\| = \sqrt{r + 2}
$$
with a suitable $r$.

Regarding the kind of set of the solution set: If we set
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &   & & 0 & 0 \\
  & 1 & &   & 0 \\
  & & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & &        & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\phantom{0} & x_1^T & \phantom{0} & 1 \\
\phantom{0} & x_2^T & \phantom{0} & 1 \\
\phantom{0} & \vdots & \phantom{0} & \vdots \\
\phantom{0} & x_{n+1}^T & \phantom{0} & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
M = B
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac12 x_1^Tx_1 \\
\frac12 x_2^Tx_2 \\
\vdots \\
\frac12 x_{n+1}^Tx_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
($M$ is the circumcenter of the simplex with the vertices $x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}$) then we get
$$ p-M = -Ba
$$
which means that the position of $p$ relatively to $M$ depends linearly on the components of $a$. As multiplication of $a$ with a positive number does not change the relative order of the components of $a$, we can conclude that, for each point $p=M+q,$ the point $M+\lambda q$ is also part of the solution that fulfills the same distance ordering. This means that the sets are actually cone-like, with their apexes at $M.$

If two choices of $a$ have the same relative order of their components, then this order will also be preserved for all of their convex combinations:
$$
a_i < a_j, \;\; a^{\star}_i < a^{\star}_j\;\;\Rightarrow
\lambda a_i+(1-\lambda) a_i^{\star}
<\lambda a_j+(1-\lambda) a_j^{\star}
\;\;,\;\;\lambda\in[0,1]
$$
As the convex combination of the $a$s maps directly to the convex combination of the corresponding $p$s, we now even know that the solution sets are convex cones.

Comment: Seems good, but what is $c$?

Comment: @samwolfe It is a sort of offset for the $a_i$. You have to add an additional degree of freedom to the system of linear equations. The system would not necessarily be solvable if you tried to fix the distances themselves. But by fixing only the differences of the squares of the distances, the system becomes solvable, with a unique solution. Therefore, there must be another variable to represent the offset of the distances.

Comment: In case of a regular simplex in three dimensions ($n=3$), the partitioning of the space into $24$ convex cones can best be demonstrated by means of the [tetrakis hexahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrakis_hexahedron). Each cone is the union of rays that start in the center and pass through one of the faces of the tetrakis hexahedron.